# Upsource - PKIX path SSL certs issue

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, jetbrains-ide, upsource

I'm stuck on this problem for a few weeks now and really not sure what do to bypass a SSL error to connect to the Upsource Jetbrains tool. I'm following the below documentation

https://upsource-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545609-Using-self-signed-certificates-to-connect-to-a-Git-repo

And added

```
sudo Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.7/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -import -alias brinternal1 -keystore /Users/camposf/Documents/upsource-2020.1.1802/bin/upsource.sh -file Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.7/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

to my terminal (I'm on a Mac) but this message keeps appearing:

```
This keystore does not support probing and must be loaded with a specified type
```

We had some issues with SSL and Java before and they were fixed by another developer but am wondering if this could have been some conflict between what was done back then and now?

This is what I believe it may have been used before but it was also for a different JDK version.

```
sudo keytool -import -alias brinternal1  -file bedrock-ca.pem -trustcacerts /Users/camposf/Documents/upsource-2020.1.1802/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

I'm very new to this type of certs work and any help is much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**

As per Dave's answer, the command used seemed to be wrong having the paths mixed up. Updated it to the below and got a confirmation message saying the certificate has been added to the keystore. However, still getting the PKIX SSL issue even after restarting the computer. Tried both locally and on docker.

```
sudo Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.7/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -import -alias brinternal2 -keystore Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.7/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -file bedrock.cer
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: **You've got it backwards.** As the page you link says, `-keystore x` should be the name of the truststore file, which is `(JREDIR)/lib/security/cacerts`, and `-file y` should be the name of the file containing the cert you want to add. You can _either_ specify `-storepass z` on the commandline _or_ enter it when prompted; either choice is valid. Your second version could be correct if it weren't missing the flag `-keystore`.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your reply. Yeah, I think you were in regard to it being backwards as tried this now  ```sudo Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.7/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -import -alias brinternal2 -keystore Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.7/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -file bedrock.cer``` and the error about probing disappeared, however the certs -pkix message is still there even after I restarted my laptop. Tried on docker too and no success there either. Any other idea what I could do please?

Comment: Look at what host(s) you are actually connecting to, and what certs it (or each of them) provides, and determine whether they are correct and if not what the problem is. If you can't give specifics on the host(s) or the cert(s) I can't give any specific advice.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try and see how to get this info.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 just to share this issue is fixed now. Thanks again for your help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **Upsource uses their own JDK**. Found out about it by typing

```
/Users/myUser/Documents/upsource-2020.1.1802/bin/upsource.sh java print
```

So fixed the issue by typing the following command on my terminal from where the certs file was located (bedrock.cert in our case):

```
sudo /Users/myUser/Documents/upsource-2020.1.1802/internal/java/mac-x64/bin/keytool -import -alias brinternal2 -keystore  /Users/camposf/Documents/upsource-2020.1.1802/internal/java/mac-x64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file bedrock.cer
```

It also seems to be possible to have Upsource to point to your own local jdk by typing

```
/Users/myUser/Documents/upsource-2020.1.1802/bin/upsource.sh java set <home path for your preferred jdk>
```

where   can be by found using the `echo $JAVA_HOME` command.

Not sure how advisable would be to change that though.